# learning how to cast numeric input

Tags: python

first time asking a question.

I am learning how to cast numeric input (learning from an edX course and using jupyter notebook). This is my code:

```
calc_1 = input("What is the first number? (use integers): ")
calc_2 = input("What is the second number? (use integers): ")

add_calcs = int(calc_1) + int(calc_2)
final_calc = int(calc_1)," + ",int(calc_2),"=",(add_calcs) 

print(final_calc)
```

**Why is my output coming out like this?:**

> What is the first number? (use integers): 1
>
> What is the second number? (use integers): 2
>
> (1, ' + ', 2, '=', 3)

Thanks in advance

Comment: @rpoleski the output will be the same in Python 3, because `final_calc` is a tuple.

Comment: Unfortunately the top right of the screen where you set which python to use is already set at python3

Comment: Please use triple backticks to format code, that makes it a bit easier to read!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
final_calc = int(calc_1)," + ",int(calc_2),"=",(add_calcs)
```

is syntactically equivalent to:

```
final_calc = (int(calc_1)," + ",int(calc_2),"=",(add_calcs))
```

So `final_calc` is a tuple, and `print` will display it as such. One way to pass it to `print`, so that it prints each item individually is:

```
print(*final_calc)
```

Comment: Went through my old submissions and realized I never thanked you for the help. Much appreciated.